# What are all the possible codes for the matrix \llbracket, \rrbracket and \llparenthesis,\rrparenthesis?

Tags: matrices, brackets

**1.** I am interested in the matrix:

[image]

To make this matrix, I am using the following code (the full document):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\newcommand{\bbrack}[1]{
\left\llbracket \begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix} \right\rrbracket}
 \newenvironment{bbsmallmatrix}{
\left\llbracket\begin{smallmatrix}}{
\end{smallmatrix}\right\rrbracket}
 \begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\bbrack{ A\\ B}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

What are other possible codes to make the same matrix?

**2.** I would like to make the same style of matrix as before but with `\llparenthesis` and `\rrparenthesis`. What are all the possible codes to make this matrix?

Comment: Rather than asking for all possible ways to do something, wouldn't it be better to tell us why you think your current approach isn't sufficient? There are _many_ ways to do the same thing in TeX...

Comment: there are infinitely many tex inputs that would make that output  what is your actual question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no single way to do it. I can propose `bbmatrix` based on `amsmath` and `ppmatrix` built by measuring the contents in order to push the parentheses near to each other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{bbmatrix}
  {\left\llbracket\env@matrix}
  {\endmatrix\right\rrbracket}
\makeatother

\newlength{\ppmatrixdim}
\newlength{\ppmatrixdimtwo}
\newlength{\ppmatrixdimthree}
\newsavebox{\ppmatrixbox}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settoheight{\ppmatrixdimtwo}{$\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}$}%
  \settoheight{\ppmatrixdimthree}{$\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}$}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\muskip_new:N \l_alezig_ppmatrix_muskip

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ppmatrix}{b}
 {
  \settoheight{\ppmatrixdim}{$\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}$}
  \bool_case:nF
   {
    { \dim_compare_p:n { \ppmatrixdim < \ppmatrixdimtwo } }
      { \muskip_set:Nn \l_alezig_ppmatrix_muskip { -3mu } }
    { \dim_compare_p:n { \ppmatrixdim < \ppmatrixdimthree } }
      { \muskip_set:Nn \l_alezig_ppmatrix_muskip { -7mu } }
   }
   {
    \muskip_set:Nn \l_alezig_ppmatrix_muskip { -9mu }
   }
  \left(\mspace{\l_alezig_ppmatrix_muskip}\left(
  \begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}
  \right)\mspace{\l_alezig_ppmatrix_muskip}\right)
 }{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{bbmatrix} a \end{bbmatrix} \\
\begin{bbmatrix} a \\ b \end{bbmatrix} \\
\begin{bbmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bbmatrix} \\
\begin{ppmatrix} a \end{ppmatrix} \\
\begin{ppmatrix} a \\ b \end{ppmatrix} \\
\begin{ppmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{ppmatrix} \\
\begin{ppmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{ppmatrix}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can try your hand for the small versions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do with `nicematrix` (but it's probably an overuse).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}{c}
a \\ b \\ c 
\end{NiceArrayWithDelims}$

\bigskip
$\begin{NiceArray}{((c))}  
a \\ b \\ c 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I don't know why but I cannot run this code. It doesn't provide an error, it doesn't even build the pdf.

Comment: Your TeX installation is probably not up-to-date.